# Angularjs Request URL: unsafe:javascript:void(0); for ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

When I call a function using ng-click it says `Request URL: unsafe:javascript:void(0);` and not working

Here is my simple code,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module("crudApp",[])
            .controller("userController",function($scope,$http){
                $scope.addUser = function(){
                    console.log('testing');
                }
            });
    </script>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addUser()">Add User</a>
```

Comment: don't use `href="javascript:void(0);"`;  try `href=""` or href="#"` instead.

Comment: any specific reason for using `href="javascript:void(0);"`????